# I am getting this error when i try to display my linkedlist

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
    public:
    int data;
    node *next;
}*head;

class linkedlist
{
private:
    node *first;
public:
    linkedlist(){first=NULL;}
    linkedlist(int A[], int n);
    ~linkedlist();
};

void linkedlist :: display(){
    node *p = first;
    while(p!=0){
        cout<<p->data<<" ";
        p=p->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    int A[]={2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    linkedlist l(A,5);
    l.display();
}
```

**I am getting this error :**

C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEQYgIh.o:ll_using_class.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `linkedlist::linkedlist(int*, int)' C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEQYgIh.o:ll_using_class.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to` linkedlist::~linkedlist()'
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEQYgIh.o:ll_using_class.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `linkedlist::~linkedlist()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: That's not the error I get. I get "_`error: no declaration matches 'void linkedlist::display()'`_" but if I fix that by adding `void display();`  to the class definition I get the same error as you because you haven't implemented the constructor `linkedlist(int A[], int n);` or the destructor `~linkedlist();`

Comment: You wrote a destructor, but you didn't provide a definition (implementation) of that destructor.

Comment: You’ve declared and used `linkedlist::linkedlist(int*, int)`, but you haven’t defined it.

Comment: yah i implemented both now. thank you

Answer (score 4):

- You've defined `void linkedlist::display()` but you haven't declared it in your class definition.
- You've declared the constructor `linkedlist(int A[], int n)` but you haven't defined it.
- You've declared the destructor `~linkedlist()` but you haven't defined it.

Other notes:

- The global `node*` `head` is pointless.
- The `node` type doesn't need to be visible outside the `linkedlist` class. I suggest hiding it by making the `node` definition private in `linkedlist`.
- The `display()` member function does not make changes to the `linkedlist` object. Make such functions `const`.

Example fixes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility> // std::exchange

class linkedlist {
private:
    struct node {     // made definition private
        int data;
        node *next;
    };

    node* first;
public:
    linkedlist();
    linkedlist(int A[], int n);
    linkedlist(const linkedlist&) = delete;            // copying not implemented
    linkedlist& operator=(const linkedlist&) = delete; // copying not implemented
    ~linkedlist();
    void add(int value); // a function to add a value to the linked list
    void display() const; // made const 
};

linkedlist::linkedlist() : first(nullptr) {}

linkedlist::linkedlist(int A[], int n) : first(nullptr) {
    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx) {
        add(A[idx]);                     // use the add() member function
    }
}

linkedlist::~linkedlist() {
    while(first) { // delete all nodes
        delete std::exchange(first, first->next);
    }
}

void linkedlist::add(int value) {
    // add a node by linking it in first
    first = new node{value, first};
}

void linkedlist::display() const {
    if(first) {
        std::cout << first->data;
        for(node* p = first->next; p; p = p->next) {
            std::cout << ' ' << p->data;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int A[]={2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    linkedlist l(A, 5);
    l.display();
}
```

Output

```
6 5 4 3 2
```

Comment: Ohh right. i made changes to my code please have a look. its working now...thanks :)

Comment: @NoobCoder You're welcome! Please don't change your question radically after you've gotten answers. The question + the answer now doesn't make sense and since this is a Q&A site, it won't help anyone else in its current state. I'll revert the change you made. You do have some problems though like `for(int i=1;i<n;i++)` which skips the first element. Arrays starts at element `0` in C++.

Comment: ohkay understood i won't do it hereafter. also, im adding first element in the first node itself.

Comment: @NoobCoder Ah.. I see. That's an unusual way of doing it. I missed that. :)

Comment: i just started to learn DSA xD